CORS violation only on Apple Silicon Macs in Flask app
I have reproduced this error with the following python backend api using flask.
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)  # Enable CORS for all routes and origins

@app.route('/api/hello', methods=['GET'])
def hello():
    name = request.args.get('name', 'World')
    message = f'Hello, {name}!'
    return jsonify({'message': message})

@app.route('/api/data', methods=['POST'])
def receive_data():
    data = request.get_json()
    # Process the received data
    processed_data = process_data(data)
    return jsonify({'processed_data': processed_data})

def process_data(data):
    # Apply upper() to all string values in the dictionary
    processed_data = {}
    for key, value in data.items():
        if isinstance(value, str):
            processed_data[key] = value.upper()
        else:
            processed_data[key] = value
    return processed_data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

And I have a front end as follows:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flask API Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Flask API Test</h1>

    <h2>GET Request</h2>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter a name">
    <button onclick="sendGetRequest()">Send GET Request</button>
    <p id="getResult"></p>

    <h2>POST Request</h2>
    <label for="data">Data:</label>
    <input type="text" id="data" placeholder="Enter some data">
    <button onclick="sendPostRequest()">Send POST Request</button>
    <p id="postResult"></p>

    <script>
     function sendGetRequest() {
         const name = document.getElementById('name').value;
         const url = `http://localhost:5000/api/hello?name=${encodeURIComponent(name)}`;

         fetch(url)
             .then(response => response.json())
             .then(data => {
                 document.getElementById('getResult').textContent = data.message;
             })
             .catch(error => {
                 console.error('Error:', error);
             });
     }

     function sendPostRequest() {
         const data = document.getElementById('data').value;
         const url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/data';

         fetch(url, {
             method: 'POST',
             headers: {
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
             },
             body: JSON.stringify({ data: data })
         })
             .then(response => response.json())
             .then(data => {
                 console.log(data.processed_data);
                 document.getElementById('postResult').textContent = data.processed_data.data;
             })
             .catch(error => {
                 console.error('Error:', error);
             });
     }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

When I go to localhost:8080 and try it out on an M3 mac, I get these errors:
localhost/:1 Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/api/hello?name=George' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
(index):26 
        
        
       GET http://localhost:5000/api/hello?name=George net::ERR_FAILED 403 (Forbidden)
sendGetRequest @ (index):26
onclick @ (index):12
(index):32 Error: TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at sendGetRequest ((index):26:10)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):12:40)

However, when I run in on my 2015 macbook pro, it works flawlessly. A colleague with an M2 mac has the error, but another colleague running windows has no problem. I have tried it on chrome and safari on my computers.
Any ideas as to what's going on here or what can be done about it??
P.S. I put all the code here: https://github.com/Duncan-Britt/cors-test if you want to try it out for yourself.

You're running from port 8080 but making requests to port 5000?

@Siguza the backend was served at 5000. The front end was served to 8080. And apparently the problem is solved by serving the backend to a different port number. Problem solved!

My teammate figured it out. Apparently the new laptops are using port 5000 for AirPlay. By serving the backend to port 5555, there is no more problem.

I'm surprised the service would start on port 5000 if it's in use? I'd expect to see the error "cannot bind to port 5000, port in use" in the logs.
